# add CSS animation to a website with background picture

Tags: html, css

The question is very silly but I've *never* created a webpage so please do not immediately downvote. AND please don't tell me to watch totorials, I really need to do something like described below only once. For some reasons, I need to make a really simple webpage, containing only a background picture and a CSS3 heart animation I found around. **I need the CSS heart animation to be postioned on the left corner with a 100px margin from bottom, overlaying the other image I use as background** What do I need to add to HTML to achieve that?

my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Test page</title>
   </style>
   </head>
  <body/>
   <center><img src="sbg.jpg" width="1280" height="800" alt="bg" /></center>
   </body>
   </html>
```

[And the CSS I'm trying to use](http://pastebin.com/69SQjFib)

SO has very poor CSS formatting so I added the CSS code to pastebin.

Please note that I never worked with CSS and need a detailed explanation. Thanks.

Comment: what differs your question to a homework? Dont ask for "dont downvote" if you think there is a reason for...this case is worse because youre not a newbie here. didnt downvoted yet btw, gonna wait your answer

Comment: it's not a homework since I finished the school and college for ages. Sure I'm not a newbie on SO but my area of work is Android. I'm a newbie in web development

Answer (score 1):

Create a

```
<div id='bigwrapper></div>
```

and style it with

```
#bigwrapper{
   width:100%;
   height:100%:
}
```

and the picture of your heart in there. After that, apply the needed CSS
The HTML markup needs work, because without properly formatted tags, several things may not work. You need to open and close tags properly.

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Test page</title>
     <style></style>
 </head>
  <body>
     <center><img src="sbg.jpg" width="1280" height="800" alt="bg" /></center>
   </body>
</html>
```

The center tag has been deprecated in HTML5, and the transitions you are using only work with HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: thanks. Well I'm definitely ain't aiming to insult SO since I'm hanging around everyday, I just pointed out some missed functionality. Cause usually people don't like any external links in questions